# Mathematica maximum of a list

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8, list-manipulation

I have a list of this form:

```
{{1.39339, 11.5378}, {1.38379, 11.5362}, {1.37495, 11.5342}, {1.36668,  11.5319}, 
 {1.35878, 11.5295}, {1.35199, 11.527}, {1.34565, 11.5246}, {1.34034, 11.5222}, 
 {1.33551, 11.52}, {1.33128, 11.5179}, {1.32784, 11.5162}, {1.32506, 11.5147}, 
 {1.32293, 11.5136}, {1.32141, 11.5129}, {1.32088, 11.5125}, {1.32088, 11.5125}, 
 {1.32141, 11.5129}, {1.32291, 11.5136}, {1.32505, 11.5147}, {1.32782, 11.5162}, 
 {1.33124, 11.5179}, {1.33545, 11.5199}, {1.34024, 11.5221}, {1.3455, 11.5245}, 
 {1.35183, 11.5269}, {1.35852, 11.5294}, {1.36633, 11.5318}, {1.3742, 11.5341}, 
 {1.38331, 11.5361}, {1.3927, 11.5377}, {1.40271, 11.5388}, {1.4132, 11.5394}, 
 {1.42442, 11.5392}, {1.43627, 11.5382}, {1.44893, 11.5362}, {1.46199, 11.5331}, 
 {1.47505, 11.5286}, {1.48909, 11.5227}, {1.5035, 11.5153}, {1.51849, 11.5061}, 
 {1.53403, 11.495}, {1.54945, 11.4818}, {1.56601, 11.4665}, {1.58208, 11.4486}, 
 {1.59901, 11.4283}, {1.61566, 11.4053}, {1.63253, 11.3794}, {1.65018, 11.3506}, 
 {1.66729, 11.3187}, {1.68435, 11.2835}, {1.70207, 11.2451}, {1.71925, 11.2033}, 
 {1.73596, 11.158}, {1.75295, 11.1093}, {1.76956, 11.0569}, {1.78543, 11.001}, 
 {1.80152, 10.9416}, {1.81648, 10.8786}, {1.83143, 10.8123}, {1.84529, 10.7424}, 
 {1.85869, 10.6694}, {1.87128, 10.5932}, {1.88324, 10.514}, {1.894, 10.4319}, 
 {1.90416, 10.3471}, {1.91301, 10.2598}, {1.92081, 10.1702}, {1.92771, 10.0785}, 
 {1.93323, 9.98488}, {1.93774, 9.88954}, {1.94094, 9.79267}, {1.94293, 9.69444}, 
 {1.94359, 9.59504}, {1.9431, 9.49462}, {1.94124, 9.39331}, {1.93819, 9.29125}, 
 {1.93387, 9.18855}, {1.92833, 9.08532}, {1.92159, 8.9817}, {1.9137, 8.87788}, 
 {1.9047, 8.77414}, {1.89464, 8.67101}, {1.88358, 8.56965}, {1.87159, 8.47408}, 
 {1.85873, 8.39549}, {1.84508, 8.32051}, {1.8289, 8.24711}, {1.81397, 8.17489}, 
 {1.79849, 8.10444}, {1.78428, 8.03572}, {1.76798, 7.97964}, {1.75143, 7.96266}, 
 {1.73472, 7.95265}, {1.71797, 7.94498}, {1.70127, 7.93857}, {1.68471, 7.933}, 
 {1.66839, 7.92807}, {1.65237, 7.92367}, {1.63682, 7.91972}, {1.62179, 7.91619}}
```

I would like *Mathematica* to consider the first value and display the two numbers which are maximum for that output. In this case I would like an output of `{1.94359, 9.59504}`.

Can you please assist?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the list is saved as `list`, one can use

```
MaximalBy[list, First]
```

> `{{1.94359, 9.59504}}`

[`MaximalBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaximalBy.html) was introduced in version 10.0.

In an earlier *Mathematica* version one can use

```
SortBy[list, First] // Last
```

> `{{1.94359, 9.59504}}`

---

If speed is significant, one should use [`Ordering`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html)

```
list[[Ordering[list[[All, 1]], -1]]]
```

Comment: Yes used the SortBy at first but the MaximalBy is a more elegant solution. Thank you :)